# How to add role to user after message is sent

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am using Discord.js to make my bot.
I want to add a role to a user after they use a command.
The command is `!attack` it will "kill" the person you pinged.

I think it might have something to do with Intents but I'm not sure. Here are my Intents right now,

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
  }, {
    partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]
  });
```

Also, here is the code for the `!attack` command,

```js
var user;
var rollNum;
var role;

module.exports = {
  name: "attack",
  category: "info",
  permissions: [],
  devOnly: false,
  run: async ({client, message, args}) => {
    user = message.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    if(user[1] === `<@${message.author.id}>`){
      message.reply("You are not allowed to kill yourself.")
    }
    else{
      message.reply("Rolling...");
      rollNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      if(rollNum >= 4){
        message.reply(`${user[1]} could not be killed. They are too strong for you lol.`);
      }
      else{
        message.reply(`${user[1]} is dead... R.I.P.`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a clear problem statement? Currently it's not at all clear what the issue you're encountering actually is - see [ask]

Comment: You've presented some code and stated what It's supposed to do, but you haven't told us what isn't working or any debugging details

Comment: I don't have any idea how to add a role to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a user a role, you need the `MANAGE_ROLES` permission and the bot also cannot give a role which has a higher position than its own. Other than that, the syntax for adding a role is pretty simple. First, you have to fetch the role, then you can add it to the user. To fetch the role, you can use `.get()` if you have the role id or `.find()` if you have the role name. Your code might look something like this:

```js
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleid') // Or message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'rolename')
message.member.roles.add(role.id).then(m => {
    message.channel.send('Successfully added the role!')
}).catch(err => {
    message.channel.send('There was an error while adding the role!')
})
```